# Node Debug From Vagrant

Tags: node.js, debugging, vagrant, remote-debugging

Unable to remote debug a node server running on a Vagrant box in Chrome from my host machine. The server is configured to run on port 8123.

Node Version: 7.10.0

In Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 9229, guest: 9229
config.vm.network :forwarded_port, host: 8123, guest: 8123
```

From my vagrant box I run:

```
$ node --inspect index.js
Debugger listening on port 9229.
Warning: This is an experimental feature and could change at any time.
To start debugging, open the following URL in Chrome:
chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&v8only=true&ws=127.0.0.1:9229/84085f07-dc42-4e1e-bdd8-532e6dc5c4c6
--- Customer Service---
Connecting to customer repository...
Connected. Starting server...
Server started successfully, running on port 8123.
```

When I try to access the url in Chrome from my host machine while I don't get an error the sources tab is empty.

[Screenshot of devTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yoSbx.png)

Comment: Is that url in Chrome correct for the network you setup?

Comment: Yup. I used the URL specified by the command output

Answer (score 6):

Based on [NodeJS 11591 issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11591). You can't access the Vagrant stuff via localhost (127.0.0.1), so you need to to specify host explicitly:

`$ node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js`

Then you need to set up Target discovery settings in the Chrome. Note that `192.168.33.11` from my sample is the static IP address providing an access to the Vargant host from the local host:

[image]

Comment: Still getting this error: 
`This site can’t be reached

The webpage at ws://0.0.0.0:9229/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: I've updated the answer to provide more details. This is how it works for me.

Comment: Starting inspector on 0.0.0.0:9229 failed: address already in use

Comment: Try to forward another port, e.g. 9228. Looks like some process handles it.

Comment: still the same
`The webpage at ws://0.0.0.0:9228/cea5114d-29c9-4561-a700-3a992cb08b7e might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_DISALLOWED_URL_SCHEME`

Comment: is it something that you got on `$ node --inspect=0.0.0.0:9229 index.js` execution?

Comment: Also, are you sure that you run `node` under the Vagrant? Because I got the same error when I'm trying to run it directly on my localhost, which is totally irrelevant to the topic. This is only for Vagrant-localhost integration.

Comment: I don't know for vagrant-localhost. I can reach same address localhost:4443 without vagrant also, but my database connection is not working then.

Comment: I recommend you to post a separate question with detailed description! Add a link to it here after it is done.